# Moving average line is only shown till last ticker.id close

Tags: moving-average, pine-script

I am working on a moving average indicator which shows the MA line of a given time frame.
For some reason is the MA line only displaced till the last ticker.id period close. So when for example I have set the indicator to show a daily MA the line is only updated when the day closes.

(Link to image https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjkvO.jpg)

Does anyone know how my indicator will be able include data between daily closes, so the line is being updated continuously?

I think this line not being updated continuously also causes the label which is supposed to be plotted right at the MA line being plotted at the 1 point / dollar height on the chart.

I have only recently started writing code, so excuse me if this is a dumb question. I have written this code looking at other indicators and trying to fit parts into my own

This is the code of the entire indicator.

```
//@version=4

study(title="Custom Timeframe SMA", shorttitle="Custom TF MA", overlay=true)

res = input(title="MA Timeframe", type=input.resolution, defval="D",options=["60", "240", "D", "W"])

length1 = input(title="SMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=50)
Label=input(title="show Labels",defval=true)

sma1 = sma(close, length1)
sourceEmaSmooth1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, sma1, barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(sourceEmaSmooth1, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="25 period", color=#a21e7b)
plotchar((sourceEmaSmooth1 ? Label : barstate.islast and not barstate.isconfirmed) ? sourceEmaSmooth1 : na, location=location.absolute, text=" 50 SMA", textcolor=#a21e7b, offset=10, editable=false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `barmerge.gaps_on` with `security()` creates *holes* which appear as `na` values at the chart's resolution, which is why your ma wasn't always showing. It wasn't apparent on historical bars because the `plot()` function fills the space from non-gap to non-gap (you could see it if you plotted circles instead of a line).

Using `barmerge.lookahead_on` with `security()` produces lookahead bias on historical bars. Very nasty if you don't index the value you're fetching, as is explained in this publication on how to use `security()` correctly: [How to avoid repainting when using security()](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/).

I added `show_last = 1` to you label-plotting call and fixed the conditional. Because it now only plots the last occurrence of the label, we no longer need to worry about barstates:

```
//@version=4

study(title="Custom Timeframe SMA", shorttitle="Custom TF MA", overlay=true)

res = input(title="MA Timeframe", type=input.resolution, defval="D",options=["60", "240", "D", "W"])

length1 = input(title="SMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=50)
Label=input(title="show Labels",defval=true)

sma1 = sma(close, length1)
sourceEmaSmooth1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, sma1)

plot(sourceEmaSmooth1, linewidth=2, title="25 period", color=#a21e7b)
plotchar(Label ? sourceEmaSmooth1 : na, location=location.absolute, text=" 50 SMA", textcolor=#a21e7b, offset=10, show_last = 1, editable=false)
```

[image]

Comment: Your comment on the code for the label was very useful, but I wonder if there really isn't a way to extend that line. You said it produces bias which I guess should be bad, but price action seems to react to it well. (watch image) Is it impossible to add an actively moving part which takes in to account the most recent price action, and if there really is no way solve this problem is it possible to just ad a dashed line which is placed from the last point to current time or next tickerid close in the same trajectory of the two previous points ? https://www.tradingview.com/x/yRJWc1cR/

Comment: You can simply plot the line in the future with a positive offset, or look into how others have done forecasting before. This is an example: [Fancy Triple Moving Averages [BigBitsIO](https://www.tradingview.com/script/7emR6ckb-Fancy-Triple-Moving-Averages-BigBitsIO/).